# Ubuntu - Save terminal tabs with directories and titles

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal

In the terminal I always have the same 3 tabs open, plus other random ones.

It would be nice if I could have the terminal open with these three tabs open and their titles set.

I tried

```
gnome-terminal --save-config=/home/user1/usertabs
```

but this doesn't save the titles I set for the tabs.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is related to the profile being used.
If the profile has its

> "Title and Command"->"When terminal commands set their own titles:" =
>   Keep initial title

then the titles find their way into the configuration file.
You can either modify the Default profile or create a new profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the symbols used in your title!, If you use special symbols like **/** you titles will be not saved.
I have shared exactly my experience, I had the same problem today.
I solved this problem today!
This answer does not repeat or contradict the accepted answer it complements the existing answer, my point is important for beginners.

Comment: Then it would be better as a comment than as an answer, don't you think ?